# How to create a bar chart with R

Tags: r

I'm an R noob and trying to figure out what I hope will be a simple question. I'm trying to create a bar chart with the data below where Moth is on the y-axis, Visits (2014) and Visits (2015) are bar charts, and Trials (2014) and Trials (2015) are a line chart. I realize this is a trivial task within Excel, however I would like to understand how this is done in R.

```
Month ; Visits (2014) ; Visits (2015) ; Trials (2014) ; Trials (2015)
Jan ;  675 ; 835  ; 31  ; 41
Feb ; 620 ; 895   ; 30  ; 41
Mar ; 713 ; 1,117 ; 33  ; 46
Apr ; 634 ; 964   ; 29  ; 41
May ; 617 ; 968   ; 30  ; 42
Jun ; 626 ; 1,120 ; 30  ; 46
Jul ; 668 ; 961   ; 31  ; 46
Aug ; 650 ; 1,109 ; 32  ; 46
Sep ; 744 ; 1,207 ; 33  ; 48
Oct ; 792 ; 1,167 ; 34  ; 45
Nov ; 710 ; 1,142 ; 32  ; 41
Dec ; 746 ;       ; 30  ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seano314 - what have you tried so far? Also, can you please put your data in a format that can be easily loaded into R, using dput?

Comment: Try ggplot. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your data cleaned up and with made-up values for December 2015.  Once the data was read into memory by R, the `dput()` function produces this for the data frame df.

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr ", "Aug ", "Dec ", "Feb ", "Jan ", 
"Jul ", "Jun ", "Mar ", "May ", "Nov ", "Oct ", "Sep "), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), Visits = c(835, 895, 
    1117, 964, 968, 1120, 961, 1109, 1207, 1167, 1142, 1000, 
    675, 620, 713, 634, 617, 626, 668, 650, 744, 792, 710, 746
    ), Trials = c(41, 41, 46, 41, 42, 46, 46, 46, 48, 45, 41, 
    40, 31, 30, 33, 29, 30, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 32, 30)), .Names = c("Month", 
"Year", "Visits", "Trials"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

The next step was to melt the data frame into a long format suitable for plotting.

```
library(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = c("Year", "Month"))         # put the data frame in long form
```

Finally, the plot, which could be done many ways but this one breaks the years into two panels.  The plot image is squished here.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.m, aes(x = Month, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = .4, position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Number", title = "Two-Year Comparison of Visits and Trials") +
  theme(axis.ticks= element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 11)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, `melt` your data

```
library(data.table)

DT <- melt.data.table(DT)
```

Then using `ggplot2`, the plot is easy to make

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DT, aes(x = Month, y = X1)) + 
    stat_bin(aes(fill = X1))
```